# Class Frontend\Auth\LoginController does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I started to upgrade a Laravel project form `v5.2` to `v5.6`. I followed the doc and made the changes listed there. now the composer update is working for 5.6 version. On the project the Authintication was managed via `Sentry` and i planned to replace that with Laravel default auth and spatie/laravel-permissions package to manage role-permissions.

I imported the package and added the controllers and routes. But the problem is i am getting the following error while accessing the `/login` route, `Class Frontend\Auth\LoginController does not exist`

I could not find the reason of getting such error. my route is defined as the following,

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Frontend', 'as' => 'frontend.'], function () {
    // includeRouteFiles(__DIR__.'/Routes/');

    /**
     * Frontend Access Controllers
     * All route names are prefixed with 'frontend.auth'.
     */
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth', 'as' => 'auth.'], function () {

        /*
        * These routes require the user to be logged in
        */
        Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
            Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
        });

        /*
         * These routes require no user to be logged in
         */
        Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
            // Authentication Routes
            Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
            Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login.post');

            // Socialite routes
            Route::get('login/{provider}', ['as' => 'social.login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@redirectToProvider']);
            Route::get('login/{provider}/callback', 'LoginController@handleProviderCallback');

            // Registration routes
            Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
            Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register')->name('register.post');

            // Password Reset Routes
            Route::get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.email');
            Route::post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email.post');

            Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.form');
            Route::post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.reset');
        });
    });

});
```

the source code of my upgraded project is available at https://gitlab.com/nasirkhan/doptor/tree/nasirkhan

Comment: What is the namespace of your LoginController?

Comment: `Frontend\Auth\LoginController` is the namespace of the controller . You can see the source code at https://gitlab.com/nasirkhan/doptor/tree/nasirkhan

Comment: did you add `Frontend\Auth` to the `autoload` in `composer.json` ?

Comment: no `Frontend\Auth` is not added to the autoload. the Here is my composer file https://gitlab.com/nasirkhan/doptor/blob/nasirkhan/composer.json